# Using jq I want to modify multiple values

Tags: jq

I have a json like this:

```json
{
  "bla": { "body": {
    "mode": "raw",
    "raw": "{\n  \"accountId\": \"1111\",\n  \"monetaryAmount\": {\n    \"amount\": 111,\n    \"exponent\": 2,\n    \"currency\": \"aaa\"\n  },\n  \"remarks\": \"consequat quis\"\n}",
    "options": {
      "raw": {
        "language": "json"
      }
    }
  }},
  "auth": {
    "type": "bearer",
    "bearer": [
      {
        "key": "token",
        "value": "{{token}}",
        "type": "string"
      }
    ]
  },
    "segg": {
        "key": "txn_id",
        "value": "{{token}}",
        "type": "string"
      },
    "slugg": {
        "key": "companyId",
        "value": "{{token}}",
        "type": "string"
      },
      "blu": [ {
        "key": "teamMemberId",
        "value": "{{token}}",
        "type": "string"
      } ]
}
```

Conditions: There can be anywhere any deep `..body.raw` strings, on these I want to do a simple search and replace (Or better: Parse the string as JSon and do some jq on that?).

And any deep objects with `.key` and .`value` (strings), in this I just want to replace the `.value="{{"+.key+"}}"`

Thanks

This is what I could do:

```
del(.. | objects | .auth)|
(.. | objects | select(.key == "teamMemberId")).value="{{teamMemberId}}"|
(.. | objects | select(.key == "accountId")).value="{{accountId}}"|
(.. | objects | select(.key == "companyId")).value="{{companyId}}"|
(.. | objects | select(.key == "transactionId")).value="{{transactionId}}"|
(.. | objects | select(.key == "txn_id")).value="{{transactionId}}"|
(.. | objects | select(.key == "limitType")).value="MONTHLY"|
(.. | objects | select(.raw | type == "string")).raw=null
```

In case of `..raw` I can not find a way to replace, and in case of `.key -> .value` I would prefer something like find by regex, and replace as mentioned. So that the whole jq expression is more compact.

Comment: Please fix the JSON example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to process the .body.raw values would be to start with:

```
(.. | try .body.raw // empty) |= fromjson
```

You can elaborate `fromjson` as per your requirements.

One way to update the .value values would be to include the following in your jq pipeline:

```
walk(if type == "object" and has("key") and has("value") 
     then .value = "{{\(.key)}}" else . end)
```

Comment: You are a blackbelt in `jq`, thanks!